# Uncaught TypeError: this.bad is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get below exception when debugged on browser Console when i try to write the following Jquery Script :
Here netPrice is 5.8333 and taxRate is 20.

```
var calculateGrossAmount = function(netPrice, taxRate) {
    if (!$.isNumeric(taxRate) || !$.isNumeric(netPrice)) {
        throw new TypeError("calculateGrossAmount: taxRate and netPrice
            must be numeric!");               
        }
        // vanilla js: (Math.round((netPrice * (1 + ((1/100) * taxRate))) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
        return new BigDecimal(netPrice)
            .multiply(new BigDecimal("1")
                .add(new BigDecimal("1")
                    .divide(new BigDecimal("100"), new MathContext(100))
                    .multiply(new BigDecimal(taxRate), new MathContext(100))), new MathContext(100))
            .setScale(2, BigDecimal.prototype.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    }
}
```

P.S I get error on return statement please help!!

Comment: Could you add the stacktrace? The return statement is a long chain of calls.

Comment: Yes, please add the stacktrace.

Comment: please add the stacktrace

Comment: Your question says `this.bad is not a function` yet there is nothing in your code to reference this?

Comment: Hi @lilezek when i try to inspect the page from browser, after navigating to the Console page i get following error message :Uncaught TypeError: this.bad is not a function

Comment: Are you sure that error come from above code?

Comment: There is no Stack Trace as such but I'm pretty sure that error is due to BigDecimal(netPrice)

Comment: @Shree yes it occured after I added the above code

Comment: I would reduce your return and make sure it is doing what you expect By the looks of things, it is not doing what you expect - maybe there are brackets in the wrong places as you are instantiating a lot of new BigDecimals